# how to requset albums and songs then send each album with the number of included songs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm currently working on a music player which has a node.js backend, this route : /explore/albums must send an array of items and each items number of songs, here is the code :

```
Router.route("/explore/albums")
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            // send all albums as JSON
            const albums = (await _Albums.find()).map(async (album) => {
                album.numberOfSongse = (await _Songs.find({ album: album.name })).length;
            });
            res.json(albums)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
```

albums saved on mongoDB doesn't have a numberOfSongs value, so i have to find the songs seperately but don't know how to send json, tried above code but it's not asnyc so res.json sends empty array.

do you have any suggestion ?

this api must send an array of objects, and each object includes default details and also numberOfSongs.

Answer (score 0):

this approach works just fine.

```
Router.route("/explore/albums")
    .get(async (req, res) => {
        try {
            // send all albums as JSON
            // Fetch all albums
            const albums = await _Albums.find();

            // Fetch number of songs for each album in parallel
            const albumsWithSongs = await Promise.all(albums.map(async (album) => {
                const numberOfSongs = await _Songs.countDocuments({ album: album.name });
                return { ...album.toObject(), numberOfSongs }; // Merge album and numberOfSongs
            }));

            res.json(albumsWithSongs);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
    })
```